# How to test a third party editor in protractor

Tags: automated-testing, protractor

I need to automate a portion of the platform that involves opening a third party editor (BeeFree) and add contents to the editor. The editor is used to create email templates and main content (text, images, dividers) need to be dragged/dropped into the main editor.

Is there any way to drag/drop elements using protractor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protractor provides an example for drag and drop in their [official API docs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions)

```
browser.actions().
    dragAndDrop(element1, element2).
    perform();
```

actions() in protractor extends the functionality in selenium-webdriver, further reading available [in the selenium-webdriver docs](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_ActionSequence.html) if you need more actions, etc.